# Fixed Position not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, layer

I have been cracking my head over this one for so many hours now in vain .. Your help is SOOO appreciated.

I'm creating a website for a friend. I usually don't use Ajax, but he purchased this template and asked me to do the modifications needed. Everything is going well, until I reached this point.

There's a gallery, and my friend wants something unique. What I want to achieve at the moment is, When a member clicks an image, it opens a page in Iframe.

I want this Iframe to cover the website, like it's an independent page (Like a layer).

I used Jquery for this purpose. I have the Iframe Container div in place. When a member clicks the image.. the Iframe div becomes visible covering the viewport.

Here's the website page.

http://weahub.com/HH2/Nature.php

It works exactly as I need it in FireFox. But on Chrome it acts differently. You can probably view the page source / CSS in your browser, but I will share the codes below.

**index.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hamada Hajuj | Photographer Portfolio</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/fi.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="description" content="Your description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">
    <meta name="author" content="Your name">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HoverEffect/css/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/device.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="HoverEffect/js/modernizr.custom.72835.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <div style='text-align:center'><a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a></div>  
    <![endif]-->
</head>


<body id="mainBody">

<script>
function closeImage() {
    $('#iframeContainer').fadeOut('normal');
    $('#iframeClose').fadeOut('normal');
    $('#mainBody').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
}
</script>

<div id="iframeContainer"></div>
<div id="iframeClose"><a onclick="closeImage();">Back to Gallary</a></div>



<div id="webSiteLoader"></div>
<div id="glob-wrap">
    <!-- end fullscreen gallery -->
    <div id="imgSpinner"></div>
    <a href="#" id="prevButton"></a>
    <a href="#" id="nextButton"></a>
    <div id="galleryHolder">
        <div id="imageHolder">
            <img src="img/bg_pic2.jpg" alt="" data-image-align="top_right">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="img/bg_pic2.jpg" data-image-align="top_right"></a></li>                  
            <li><a href="img/bg_pic3.jpg" data-image-align="top_left"></a></li>                  
            <li><a href="img/bg_pic1.jpg" data-image-align="top_right"></a></li>                  
            <li><a href="img/bg_pic4.jpg"></a></li>                  
            <li><a href="img/bg_pic5.jpg"></a></li>                  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end fullscreen gallery -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <!--logo and company name-->  
            <h1><a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Hamada Hajuj Photographer Portfolio"></a></h1>
            <!--menu-->   
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
                <div class="navbar-header"> 
                    <nav id="mainNav" data-follow="location" data-type="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/gall.php">gallery</a>
                                <div class="sf-mega">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Urban City</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Studio Modeling</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
                                        <li class="last"><a href="Nature.php">Nature</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/about.php">about me</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/blog.php">blog</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/contacts.php">contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <article id="content" data-follow="location" data-type="switcher">
    </article>




    <div id="other_pages" class="container" data-follow="location" data-type="switcher" data-flags="ajax">
        <?php /*
        <!--<div id="gallery" data-id="gallery"></div>-->
        */?>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <ul class="soc_links follow-links">
            <li><a href="#" class="facebook"><img src="img/soc_icon1.png" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="googleplus"><img src="img/soc_icon2.png" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="twitter"><img src="img/soc_icon3.png" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="copyright">&copy; <span id='year'></span> &bull; <a href="/privacy.php">privacy policy</a><br><!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} --></div>
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
```

**ajax/Nature.php :**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contacts</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" style="float:center;">
                <h3 style="margin-top:-20px; margin-bottom:20px;">Gallery --> Nature</h3>


<script>
function loadImage(id) {
    document.getElementById('iframeContainer').innerHTML='<iframe class="imageIframe" src="http://akramabdulfattah.com"></iframe>';
    var width=$( window ).width();
    var height=$( window ).height();
    $("#iframeContainer").css("width", width);
    $("#iframeContainer").css("height", height);
    $("#mainBody").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
    $("#iframeContainer").fadeIn(0500);
    $("#iframeClose").fadeIn(0500); 
}

</script>               

                        <a onclick="loadImage(123);"><img src="Photos/Nature_Pic1_Thumbnail.jpg" alt="Nature Image 1" class="thumbImage"><div class="hover"><span class="icon"></span></div></a><br>
                        <a onclick="loadImage(123);"><img src="Photos/Nature_Pic1_Thumbnail.jpg" alt="Nature Image 1" class="thumbImage"><div class="hover"><span class="icon"></span></div></a>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**and in my style sheet I have this (concerning this activity) :**

```
/*IFrame for images */
#iframeContainer {
   position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display:none;
  z-index: 8000;
}

.imageIframe {
    z-index:8000;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#iframeClose {
    z-index:8010;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    color:white;
}
```

**Things I have already tried :**
I read that Chrome changed few settings regarding rendering fixed position with Z-index, or using fixed position with transformed objects. I tried clear all transformation in Z and in 3D , didn't work, and tried do it with only fixed position (no z-index) and didn't work either. I tried some desperate solutions as well, not worth mentioning, and all I concluded is, Chrome is ignoring the fixed positioning for some reason that I can't figure out :(

your help is HIGHLY APPRECIATED.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: I have the actual link :http://weahub.com/HH2/Nature.php

Still better make a jsfiddle? (never used it before) and of what I want or of what I have (the problem)? ^^

Comment: Where is your [normalizer?](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: From my bootstrap.css :
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.0.0
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by mdo and fat.
 */
/*! normalize.css v2.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */


So, included in the bootstrap.css I see.

Comment: It is working on my chromebook I think. It opens up what looks like a new window, but there is nothing to go back too so I assuming it is working the way you want. I am on chrome, and personally I think this is not a good feature, more of a "what just happend"?

Comment: If I scroll down to the bottom of the page, then click the image. The Iframe is cropped from the top. Basically positioned at 0,0 to the html doc, not to the browser window. Here's a screen shot: http://prntscr.com/2cn1q5  also in FireFox, the iFrame has a scroll bar. Also, there's a "Back To Gallery" at the top left of the Iframe. (Well supposed to be there if Fixed Position works alright).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's happening because of the "perspective" css properties you have your style.css file (it's not in the code you pasted, but it's in the source file on the site you linked to).

You can remove these lines in the style.css file:

```
perspective: 1000px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000px;
-moz-perspective: 1000px;
-o-perspective: 1000px;
```

I don't know what they are there for, but when I removed them it seemed to fix your issue without altering anything else that I could see.

Comment: Oh my god, man you are a life saver!!!! As I said this is a template that my friend brought :/ , but never expected this. Removing it did cause very little bug on other pages that I can easily overcome. 

Thank you man!! been stuck on this for 2 days.