# CSS Position Fixed not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following webpage;

http://www.bredentacademy.co.uk/courses/bredent-group-day/

When scrolling, the box with booking information is meant to scroll down the page with the window, which works fine on Firefox, IE and Safari, but on Chrome it stays up top (despite the inspector visually laying out the box where it should be).

The Jquery to add the fixed class to the box is pretty simple;

```
function fixScroll() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 295) {
        $('.booking_box').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.booking_box').removeClass('fixed');
    }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        fixScroll();
    });
});
```

And the fixed class just has these declarations;

```
    &.fixed {
        float: left;
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 12px;  
        width: 340px;   
        @media #{$s1200} {
            width: 274px;
        }   
        @media #{$s992} {
           position: inherit !important;
           top: auto !important;
           width: auto !important;
        }               
    }
```

The box itself just sits inside a bootstrap column.

I've seen a few questions with similar issues, but can't find a solution and the whole thing is baffling me! I'm using Bootstrap, but can't see any conflicts there either.

If anybody can spot where I'm going wrong, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Found it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708940/fixed-position-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D, of all the ones I looked at I didn't see that one, and to be honest I hadn't searched wide enough to see how unrelated elements could have been affecting it. I need to research into why this property seems to cause this problem in Chrome but not Safari!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added  `-webkit-perspective: 1000;` in `.mobile_panel`.

```
.mobile_panel {        
    -webkit-perspective: 1000; //remove this
}
```

Remove it.. And your fixed block will work perfectly

Comment: That's worked perfectly thank you. Interesting that that property is a requirement of animating the menu on a mobile device. I've gotten round it by only applying webkit-perspective on small screeb devices, so all is working well now.